# window.open error only in IE - Invalid argument

Tags: javascript, window.open, invalid-argument

I have a simple calendar popup window come up when a date on the calendar is clicked. The code below works in Opera, FF and Chrome but not in IE6-8. It comes up with the `Error on Page` at the bottom and shows the error `invalid argument`.

```
<div class="day-number">1</div>
<td class="calendar-day" onclick="window.open('http://www.cal.com/admin/editevents.php?day=2&month=4&year=2011', 
'Edit Events', 'scrollbars=1,width=600,height=475');">
```

Could someone help me out and spot what I'm doing right but wrong according to IE?

Comment: possible duplicate of [window.open throws invalid argument in IE7-8-9b](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4840369/window-open-throws-invalid-argument-in-ie7-8-9b)

Comment: @Pekka Could be but the question is different. That question also did not come up when asking this question.

Comment: the comment above is created automatically by the system when one votes to close a question as a duplicate of another. It wasn't  meant as an accusation that you didn't search :) But it clearly *is* a duplicate.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The window name shouldn't have a space. Try `EditEvents`.

Comment: Just found it also doesn't like hyphens '-'

Answer (score 1):

```
window.open(theURL,winName,features);
```

ex: `window.open('google.com','Edit Events','width=100'); //false`

```
window.open('google.com','EditEvents','width=100'); //True
```

=> 
Edit Events //false

EditEvents //true

=>winName doesn't have spaces.