# SCRIPT87: Invalid argument in IE 9, ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, internet-explorer

This is working in all other browsers except IE. I am building a link in the code behind in c#:

```
string link = <a onclick=\"Myfunction('" + Server.UrlEncode(mystring) + "');\" href=\"javascript:void(0);\">Open Pop Up Window</a>
```

This is my javascript function:

```
 function Myfunction(pMyString) {
        CloseWindow();

        var url = "DomainPath/MyPage.aspx?Site=" + pMyString;
        win = window.open(url, "Manage Domain", 'toolbar=no,location=no,status=no,directories=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=no,width='+700+',height='+500);
    }
```

If the function is added to an onclick method in the aspx page, it works in IE. It seems to be only when I am building the link dynamically in the code behind. It will not accept any values as a parameter, and IE always outputs the error: SCRIPT87: Invalid argument with a line number to my function, however I am unable to debug. Have a missed something?

Here is the html output:

```
<td><a onclick="Myfunction('urlformyexample.com');" href="javascript:void(0);">Open Pop Up Window</a></td>
```

Comment: Please also post the html that is generated.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I have updated my post with the html. The variable I pass will be domain names, which is why I have that as the parameter.

Comment: "however I am unable to debug. Have a missed something?". Yes, you missed the built-in IE debugger.

Comment: maybe your IE disabling javascript

Comment: @kirilloid - not sure why there are always remarks like this on this site. I am unable to debug in that the debugger does not stop at any breakpoints, just throws the error.

Comment: Hmmm. If you want to write onclick inline, try adding `return false;` into your code.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4840369/window-open-throws-invalid-argument-in-ie7-8-9b

Answer (score 47, accepted):

IE9 debugger works and fails on your window.open command.

IE doesn't like the space in the `windowName` argument – "Manage Domain".

Remove any spaces, hyphens, and underscores (unless you want `_blank`) and try again.

Comment: ie9 does not like underscores nor dots in the window name. Sad!

Comment: +1. Turns out hyphens in the window name also break window.open() in IE9.

Comment: developer tools... look at exception details