# In Internet explorer, <a href> cannot jump to another page

Tags: javascript, html, web

This is a menu, click  to enter the new page, The URL is placed in the href attribute,but in IE browser can not jump

**In other browsers there is no problem.**

```
<html>
 <head></head>
 <body>
  <a data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" class="a-l"> <img id="National_img_1" /> Menu <span class="caret"></span> </a> 
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" id="National"> 
   <li><a href="Index_Action!getAll.action" class="lang-select">BB</a></li> 
   <li><a href="two_Action!getAll.action" class="lang-select">CC</a></li> 
   <li><a href="for_Action!getAll.action" class="lang-select">DD</a></li>
  </ul>
 </body>
</html>
```

I tried the following method：

1. Add the button tag to `<a>`

   2.use `<a href=“javascript:void(0)” onclick=“window.location.href='for_Action!getAll.action'>`

Still can't jump to other pages.

**The environment is in Internet explorer 8，To support it**

JavaServer Pages technology

[window.location.href not working on IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18278777/window-location-href-not-working-on-ie)
 [Invalid argument in IE 9, ASP.NET C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9590282/script87-invalid-argument-in-ie-9-asp-net-c-sharp)

Comment: What does `jump` mean in this context?

Comment: Do you meant "jump to anchor" ? in this case you missed the "#" in the beginning of the href

Comment: The `<a>` in the code you're showing doesn't link to anything, and the latter option you mention below that is a syntax error.  If you want a link to take the user to a new page, why don't you just put the URL for that page in the `href` attribute?  What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [window.location.href not working on IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18278777/window-location-href-not-working-on-ie)

Comment: your x.action seems to be wrapped with strange quotes, outer should be `""`, inner should be `''` (as you present it, it doesn't really look like its closed). Also, do have a look at console messages

Comment: See also [How do I redirect to another webpage?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/503093/215552)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your IE version is compatible for HTML5 or not first
You can use https://www.greasespot.net/. This is software which modifies loaded HTML pages

Some adaptations of it (of unknown quality) exist for IE11 :

[GreasemonkIE](https://www.greasespot.net/)
[TrixIE WPF4.5 beta](https://sourceforge.net/projects/trixiewpf45/)
Assuming that one of them works

Comment: What does this have to do with HTML5?

Answer (score 0):

why are you using javascript in a href attribute

try

```
var element = document.getElementsByClassName("class")[0];

element.addEventListener("click", function(event){
 window.location.href = "your_location"
});
```

Comment: I know it can't be written like this, I want to express the general, thank you for your advice, but this method, can't

Answer (score -1):

Try after adding file extension in href. Make sure your files exist in the same folder. I have tried after adding the extension of the target file and it is working fine.

Comment: Yes, it's all in the same file, but not in Internet explorer